# Северная (Центральная, Южная) Италия; а если просто Север?

Tags: прописная-строчная, топонимика

Прописной он или строчной, когда из контекста понятно (а понятно ли?), что речь о Северной Италии?

> Италия пустеет. Нет больше тех, кто готов приправлять пляжные радости
>   культурными изысками. Всё реже встречаются и те, кто решительно
>   настроен объять необъятное – путешествует из города в город в поисках
>   прекрасного, которое изменит его жизнь. **И особенно заметно это на
>   Севере, который с конца октября уже начал обволакивать туристов
>   туманами и пугать тоскливым дождём.** По мне – нет ничего прекраснее
>   межсезонья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Италия пустеет. Нет больше тех, кто готов приправлять пляжные радости культурными изысками. Всё реже встречаются и те, кто решительно настроен объять необъятное – **и путешествует из города в город в поисках прекрасного**, которое изменит его жизнь. И особенно заметно это на Севере, который с конца октября уже **начинает** обволакивать туристов туманами и пугать тоскливым дождём. По мне **же** – нет ничего прекраснее межсезонья.

Пояснение

1) ...настроен объять необъятное – и путешествует... Авторское тире **между однородными сказуемыми**.

2) ***Север*** с прописной буквы только как **авторский термин** в данном предложении. Он имеет здесь **метафорическое значение** и распространен придаточным определительным предложением, поэтому нельзя сказать *Север Италии* или *север страны*.

3) **Частица ЖЕ** для противопоставления мнения автора, которого не пугают дожди.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что правильно надо так:
*Всё реже встречаются и те, кто решительно настроен объять необъятное – **путешествовать** из города в город...* (то есть решительно настроен путешествовать).

Речь идет о северных районах Италии (без конкретного указания), поэтому я бы написала "на севере" со строчной буквы — по смыслу получается ***на севере*** страны (можно и так обозначить).